# view in EMC XDB "Xml data Base"

Tags: xml, xquery, emc, xml-database

How can i create a logical view in EMC XDB ?
if any other solution rather than creating views , kindly inform me.
I want to eliminate using of joins in xquery statements as it affect on performance

Answer (score 0):

xDB does not support views. Having said that, however, most performance problems with joins can, in our experience, typically be addressed by a combination of one or more of:

- optimizing/rewriting the queries (narrowing down the result set early; basing the joins on the most selective attributes; etc.)
- using appropriate indexes
- "denormalizing" the XML structure to eliminate (some) joins.